# Calculate Big O Notation

Tags: algorithm, pseudocode, notation

I currently have the following pseudo code, and I am trying to figure out why the answer to the question is O(n).

```
sum = 0;
for (i = 0; i < n; i++) do
    for (j = n/3;j < 2*n; j+= n/3) do
        sum++;
```

I thought the answer would be O(n^2) since the first for loop would run 'n' times and the second for loop has += n/3, giving it another (n divided by something times), which would just simplify to O(n^2). Could somebody explain why it is O(n)?

Answer (score 1):

This is because the second loop runs in constant amount of operations (does not depend on `n`). From `n/3` to `2n` with a step `n/3` which is similar to from `1/3` to `2` with a step `1/3`.

This will run 5-6 times for reasonable `n` (not 0) (the number is not important and depends on how do you calculate `/`)

Comment: So if the inner loop was changed to:

   for (j = n/3;j < 2n; j+= 3) do
would the runtime be O(n^2)?

Comment: yes, because now your inner loop would run in `O(n)` time.

Answer (score 1):

The inner loop increments by a multiple of `n`, not by 1, so its runtime is bounded by a constant (6?). So the total number of steps is bounded by a constant multiple of `n` (namely 6`n`).